# how to get output from println and correctly compare with another String in java

Tags: java, printing

to read a program's println output of a program I redirected the output of all `system.out.println()` into a file. This is done as such.

```
        File file = new File(fileName);
        PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(file);
        System.setOut(stream);
```

From that file I transform it into a string using

```
  public static String getFileOutput(String fileName) throws IOException {
        Path filePath = Path.of(fileName);

        String content = Files.readString(filePath);
        return content;
  }
```

when trying to compare with a string that seems to be exactly the same, I use

```
received.equals(expected)
```

and example of the output would be

```
assert test failed
received: Unknown command Dark_visual
Unknown command  Portrait_application

expected: Unknown command Dark_visual
Unknown command  Portrait_application
```

which comes from the the snippet

```
        if(received.equals(expected)){
            System.out.println("assert test passed");
            SetupContext.deleteFile(filename);
        }else{
            System.out.println("assert test failed");
            System.out.println("received: "+ received);
            System.out.println("expected: "+ expected);

        }
```

The string I was comparing to was

```
"Unknown command Dark_visual\n" + "Unknown command  Portrait_application\n"
```

My question would be, is there a way to get a more in-depth representation of what is in the file, that might contain hidden characters such as `\n` in order to be able to write the correct expected string?

Comment: `System.out.println()` appends a platform-specific line separator. If you are running this on windows, the separator is `\r\n`, which will make your test fail.

Comment: You could use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a file.

Comment: @f1sh thankyou verymuch in certain scenarios it works but other not, as like in the example given. Where it is multiple println. For a single println it works but with ```"Unknown command Dark_visual\r\n" + "Unknown command  Portrait_application\r\n"``` it didn't

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem as a means to store the file?

Comment: There doesn't need to be a file.  You can create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, hook it up to `System.out`, then run all your `System.out.println` commands.  At the end, you can retrieve the contents of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` either as a `byte[]` or as a `String`, and check what's there.

Comment: @f1sh after inspection it does work with adding ```\r\n``` i simply added it one too many times